# How to use a clone in a Rust thread

Tags: rust, thread-safety, condition-variable

In this rust program, inside the run function, I am trying to pass the "pair_clone" as a parameter for both threads but I keep getting a mismatched type error? I thought  I was passing the pair but it says I'm passing an integer instead.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};
fn producer(pair: &(Mutex<bool>, Condvar), num_of_loops: u32) {
     let (mutex, cv) = pair;
    //prints "producing"    
    }

}

fn consumer(pair: &(Mutex<bool>, Condvar), num_of_loops: u32) {
let (mutex, cv) = pair;
//prints "consuming"
    }
}

pub fn run() {
    println!("Main::Begin");
    let num_of_loops = 5;
    let num_of_threads = 4;
    let mut array_of_threads = vec!();

    let pair = Arc ::new((Mutex::new(true), Condvar::new()));
    for pair in 0..num_of_threads {
        let pair_clone = pair.clone();
        array_of_threads.push(std::thread::spawn( move || producer(&pair_clone, num_of_loops)));
        array_of_threads.push(std::thread::spawn( move || consumer(&pair_clone, num_of_loops)));
    }

    for i in array_of_threads {
        i.join().unwrap();
    }    


    println!("Main::End");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main errors

**The first**: you are using the name of the pair as the loop index. This makes `pair` be the integer the compiler complains about.

**The second**: you are using one copy while you need two, one for the producer and the other for the consumer

---

***After Edit***

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};
fn producer(pair: &(Mutex<bool>, Condvar), num_of_loops: u32) {
    let (mutex, cv) = pair;
    //prints "producing"

}

fn consumer(pair: &(Mutex<bool>, Condvar), num_of_loops: u32) {
    let (mutex, cv) = pair;
//prints "consuming"
}

pub fn run() {
    println!("Main::Begin");
    let num_of_loops = 5;
    let num_of_threads = 4;
    let mut array_of_threads = vec![];

    let pair = Arc ::new((Mutex::new(true), Condvar::new()));
    for _ in 0..num_of_threads {
        let pair_clone1 = pair.clone();
        let pair_clone2 = pair.clone();
        array_of_threads.push(std::thread::spawn( move || producer(&pair_clone1, num_of_loops)));
        array_of_threads.push(std::thread::spawn( move || consumer(&pair_clone2, num_of_loops)));
    }

    for i in array_of_threads {
        i.join().unwrap();
    }


    println!("Main::End");
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4bffe06b8b06a3b4064863c0b08d02ea)

---

Note that I haven't given any attention to the code quality. just fixed the compile errors.